# Show that a positive integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is prime if and only if $\gcd(n,m)=1$ for all $0<n<m$.

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Show that a positive integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is prime if and only if $\gcd(n,m)=1$ for all $0<m<n$.

I know that I can write $n=km+r$ for some $k,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ since $n>m$

and also that $1=an+bm$. for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

Further, I know that $n>1$ if I'm to show $n$ is prime.

I'm not sure how I would go about showing this in both directions though.

Comment: From the reverse direction, it is easy. Since $n$ is co-prime to all integers lesser than it, $n$ has to be prime.

Comment: Not true. Counterexample: $n=1$.

Comment: As stated, by my book's definition of prime, $n>1$.

Comment: Well, then, technically speaking, you must specify that n > 1 as the statement is true for n =1.  Or you can say for this exercise 1 is prime.  But if n > 1, and n is coprime to all numbers less than it, then no number less than it divides it except 1.  As no larger number can divide a smaller non zero number, no number divides n except n and 1.  So it is prime.  Likewise if n is prime it will have have no factors but itself and one so it's gcd with any number is 1 or n.  No number less than n can have a factor of n so gcd (n,m) =1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $d$ divides $n$, then $gcd(d,n)=d$.

Comment: Correct, so that help in the forward direction, but what about the other direction?

Comment: It is supposed to help for both directions. A prime is trivially coprime to any other number, and if $gcd(n,m)=1$ for all $0<m<n$, use my hint to show that $n$ has no nontrivial divisor.

Comment: I'm afraid that I still don't follow. Am I supposed to show that $d$ divides $m$ as well and thus $d=1$? If so, I'm having trouble figuring out how.

Comment: The point is gcd (n,m) is always a factor of n.  If n is prime this factor must be 1.  If all the gcds are 1 then n has no factors

Answer (score 1):

This should be trivial.

If n is prime it has no factors but 1 and n. So gcd (n,m) can only equal 1 or n.  If gcd(n,m) = n then that means n|m.  So m $\ge$ n.  So if m < n then gcd (n,m)=1.

That's one way.

If gcd (n,m)=1 for all m < n, then no number less than n divides n (other than 1).  As no number *larger* n divides n, n has no divisors except itself and 1.  So n is prime.

That's the other way.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written on the right of the iff. is the definition of a prime number. You have just stated it using more concise notation.

According to the [wolfram page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumber.html) for *Prime Number*,

> A prime number (or prime integer, often simply called a "prime" for short) is a positive integer p>1 that has no positive integer divisors other than 1 and p itself.